# How can I parse and format this string date 2022-11-08 10:28:04.282551-06?

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

I have this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String fecha = "2022-11-08 10:28:04.282551-06";
        
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        Date e = simpleDateFormat.parse(fecha);
        SimpleDateFormat newSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        System.out.println(newSimpleDateFormat.format(e));
        
    }
```

And this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2022-11-08 10:28:04.282551-06"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at Ejemplos.main(Ejemplos.java:11)
```

I want my new date like this: **2022-11-08 10:28:04.282551**
This values after dot *282551 *sometimes can be less, for example: *282 *or *2825* and sometimes there is not a dot, for example: *2022-11-08 10:28:04-06*

Comment: Ask the date's producer for a stable representation of this date & time, best is ISO8601 date time format. If that is not possible, you could use java.util.regex.Pattern to determine the format upfront, before selecting the appropriate [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Do not use SimpleDateFormat or Date any more, switch to the types from java.time.*

Comment: I strongly recommend you do not use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. They are troublesome and long outdated. Also there is no way that `SimpleDateFormat` can parse 6 decimals of fraction of second, so it is not going to work. Use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, possibly also `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`; all are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strongly recommended to stop using the outdated `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, ... classes - these were replaced by classes from the `java.time` package and sub-packages like `LocalDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime`, `DateTimeFormatter`, ...

Since we have a fractional part with variable size, we need the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to create the corresponding formatter for parsing the string. In it we are reusing the existing `ISO_LOCAL_TIME`, which handles the requirement by accepting from no fraction up to 9 decimals of fraction of second.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter PARSE_FORMATTER = 
        new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
                .appendLiteral(' ')
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME) // accepts presence or absence of fraction
                .appendOffset("+HHmm", "+00") // accepts -06 and +0530
                .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);  // replace as needed

public static OffsetDateTime convert(String str) {
    return OffsetDateTime.parse(str, PARSE_FORMATTER);
}
```

To have a string like "2022-11-08 10:28:04.282551" format, we need an additional formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMAT_FORMATTER = 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");  // time zone is IGNORED!!

public static String convertToString(OffsetDateTime dateTime) {
    return dateTime.format(FORMAT_FORMATTER);
}
```

The previous both methods can (obviously) be merged together in one method, but it is preferable to work with date-time objects (`ZonedDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime`, `LocalDateTime`, ...) instead of strings - strings should only be used for input and output!

The above Formatter is not including the time zone information in the result, that can be very confusing (IMHO) - see last date of test output below.   Please be sure that such is really required!!!
Otherwise we may convert the `OffsetDateTme` into a `ZonedDateTime` like in   `dateTime.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(FORMAT_FORMATTER);`
or include the time zone information in the output formatter as shown at the bottom.

---

Test for above methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // just for testing
    Locale.setDefault(Category.DISPLAY, Locale.GERMANY);
    Locale.setDefault(Category.FORMAT, Locale.GERMANY);
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
    
    var data = """
        2022-11-08 10:28:04.282551-06
        2022-11-08 10:28:04.282-06
        2022-11-08 10:28:04-06
        2022-11-08 10:28:04+02
        """.split("\n");
    for (var str : data) {
        test(str);
    }
}

private static void test(String str) {
    try {
        System.out.printf("%-30s  ->  %s%n", str, convertToString(convert(str)));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.printf("%-30s  ->   %s%n", str, ex);
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> openjdk version "20-ea" 2023-03-21
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 20-ea+12-790)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20-ea+12-790, mixed mode, sharing)
> 2022-11-08 10:28:04.282551-06   ->  2022-11-08 10:28:04.282551
> 2022-11-08 10:28:04.282-06      ->  2022-11-08 10:28:04.282000
> 2022-11-08 10:28:04-06          ->  2022-11-08 10:28:04.000000
> 2022-11-08 10:28:04+02          ->  2022-11-08 10:28:04.000000
> ```

If we want to make sure that the output is some specific time zone, we can for example specify it on the format formatter like this:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMAT_FORMATTER = 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
                .withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
```

Now the output will be:

> ```
> 2022-11-08 10:28:04.282551-06   ->  2022-11-08 17:28:04.282551
> 2022-11-08 10:28:04.282-06      ->  2022-11-08 17:28:04.282000
> 2022-11-08 10:28:04-06          ->  2022-11-08 17:28:04.000000
> 2022-11-08 10:28:04+02          ->  2022-11-08 09:28:04.000000
> ```

Edit: the version of the parse formatter first presented in this answer was:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter PARSE_FORMATTER = 
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")  // date time
    .optionalStart()
    .appendFraction(ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND, 3, 6, true)  // optional fractions
    .optionalEnd()
    .appendPattern("x")  // time zone offset
    .toFormatter()
    .withLocale(Locale.ROOT);  // replace as needed
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for your problem. first you need to split your string and after that you can format it. try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String fecha = "2022-11-08 10:28:04.282551-06";
    String[] parts = fecha.split("\\.");
    String part1 = parts[0];
    String part2 = parts[1];

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.parse(part1));

}
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. (1) Using `SimpleDateFormat` is not recommended (though it was also used in the question). (2) It’s wrong. You are ignoring the fraction of second and the offset. The former gives rise to an inaccuracy of under a second, the latter of up to 26 hours, which probably is not acceptable. Expected result in my time zone (Europe/Copenhagen, 1 hour ahead of UTC): `Tue Nov 08 17:28:04 CET 2022`. Observed result: `Tue Nov 08 10:28:04 CET 2022`. It is wrong by 7 hours.